# .htaccess: difference between to deny from all expressions

Tags: php, .htaccess

last days I saw two different types in order to deny access via htaccess.

I usually use this in my htaccess:

```
deny from all
```

but yesterday I saw that:

```
<Files "*.*">
Deny from all
</Files>
```

What is the difference? Does anybody know?
Thank you

Comment: [Read](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files)

Comment: I know that, thank you... That is why I am wondering. Using "Files" in combination with "*.*" doesn't make sense! So are both examples the same?

Comment: It is fairly simple, `<Files "*.*">` will match all the files that have dot `.` in the file name, like: `text.txt`, `info.php`, etc.; and it will not match files like `README`, `licence`, etc. If you wish to match all the files, you can use `<Files "*">`.

Comment: ok, but what is the differnce compared to the first example? Just "deny from all" without the File-lines...?

Comment: Quote: `Contains directives that apply to matched filenames`. `<Files "*.*">` will not match files that don't have `.` in the name.

Comment: oh yeah... directives! and "deny from all" alone applies to every file and folder?

Comment: Yes. But so does `<Files "*.*">` apply to all files in current folder and all subdirectories. If you wish to limit `<Files>` to specific directory, use `<Directory>`, [read](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory).